# Convert JSON output to an array with SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I have this `subJSON["guestpics"]` as JSON data from SwiftyJSON.

When I `print(subJSON["guestpics"])` I have this:

```
[
  "/images\/profile_pic\/1.jpg",
  "/images\/profile_pic\/2.jpg",
  "/images\/profile_pic\/3.jpg"
]
```

How can I convert this to an array ?

```
 for (_, subJSON): (String, JSON) in json[0]["data"] {
     print(subJSON["guestpics"])
 }
```

Comment: So, what is the type of subJSON["guestpics"], it seems like it is an array of strings.

Comment: [JSON] ? it comes from let json = JSON(jsonData)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftyJSON has already parsed your JSON data and prepared typed objects.

If the key `subJSON["guestpics"]` contains an array, then use SwiftyJSON's optional getter `.array` to get it:

```
if let guestPicsArray = subJSON["guestpics"].array {
    // here "guestPicsArray" is your array
}
```

Comment: Eric is correct. The JSON is already parsed when you call the `JSON (data: ...)` method. Therefore when you query for the guestpics key doing `subJSON["guestpics"]` you already have an array of strings. So you can do something like Eric suggested or `let array = subJSON["guestpics"].array` to store the array in a variable.

Comment: By the way, how can i loop this guestPicsArray ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not directly storing the value of the key in the array? as it look like array 
Does it show any error/crash when you are trying to store ?

```
if let arrGuest = subJSON["guestpics"] as? Array<String> {

}
```

Or if you are more familiar with Objective-c

```
if let arrGuest = arr as? NSArray {

}
```

you can get the array in the arrGuest object